# Value update after finish job works in text file with Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have my text data like this and I mark * charset to check unfinished job.

[image: pt]

And here's my part of code.
I want to make it when txt lines are start with * charset, it should be processed and after that processed string's * charset should be removed.

```
fs.readFile('data.txt', async function (err, data) {
    if (err) throw err;
    let array = data.toString().split("\n");
    for (i in array) {
      if (array[i].charAt(0) === '*') {
        console.log(`Now Processing : ${array[i]} | ${array.length - i -1} items left`);
        //
        // SOME JOBS
        //


        let newValue = array[i].replace('*', '');

        fs.writeFile('data.txt', newValue, 'utf-8', function (err, data) {
          if (err) throw err;
          console.log('Done!');
        })

      } else {
        console.log(`${array[i]} Already Captured`)
      }
```

Comment: Currently, you are writing the file every time you read a line. What about writing the file AFTER your for loop ended?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand you are trying to read through a file, find lines containing "*" character, doing some work, then removing the * from the affected lines.

Firstly, the call to `fs.writeFile` is happening inside a loop, so every iteration of that loop calls the writeFile function. [From the nodejs docs](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefile_file_data_options_callback) this method will "... asynchronously write data to the file, replacing the file if it already exists." You are replacing the file with every iteration. What you want to do is use `fs.appendFile` or better yet pass the 'append' system flag to writeFile. [System flags can be seen here.](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_file_system_flags) Take a look at the 'a' flag and pass it in the options object of writeFile.

Your usage of async in the readFile callback is incomplete also as you don't call await within that callback.

```js
fs.readFile('data.txt', async function (err, data) {
    if (err) throw err;
    let array = data.toString().split("\n");
    for (i in array) {
        if (array[i].charAt(0) === '*') {
        console.log(`Now Processing : ${array[i]} | ${array.length - i -1} items left`);
        //
        // SOME JOBS
        //


        let newValue = array[i].replace('*', '');
        newValue = newValue + '\n';

        await fs.appendFile('data.txt', newValue, 'utf-8', function (err, data) {
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log('Done!');
        })

        } else {
        console.log(`${array[i]} Already Captured`)
        }
    }
});
```